# What is the probability that both the first person and the last person in the row is a girl?

Tags: probability

A group includes 5 boys and 5 girls which are randomly placed in a row. What is the probability that both the first person and the last person in the row is a girl?

I tried to visualize it but I don't know how calculate the probability in this exercise.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: heres a similar post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063960/probability-question-arranging-20-pupils-in-a-row-8-boys-and-12-girls?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, pick two girls and sit them on the ends. Then complete with the remaining people. This can be done in $2\cdot {5 \choose 2}\cdot 8!$ ways. So, the probability would be $\frac{2\cdot{5 \choose 2}\cdot 8!}{10!} = \frac{2}{9}$.

Comment: Of course. Thank you very much to both of you.

Answer (score 2):

The probability that there is a girl in the first row is $\frac{5}{10}=\frac{1}{2}$. Then the probability that there is a girl in the front **and** last row is $$\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{9}= \frac{2}{9}$$